# Build version of react project does not redirect site properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I built the project using "npm run build", then used the "serve -s build" command, so it's hosted on localhost:5000.

The project itself is in React while it can redirect to some other included sites which are in vanilla html/js.

I redirect the site using this command:

```
<BrowserRouter>
       <Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="tv/indextv.html?m="+auth.currentUser.email+"&p="+othermail+"&t="+othertoken}} />
      </BrowserRouter>
```

*Without building*, (just using npm start), this happens:

The url changes as it should to `localhost:3000/tv/indextv.html?m=...&p=..&t=...` , and the site itself shows that vanilla javascript html page.

*Using the build version:*

```
http://localhost:5000/tv/indextv
```

And the site itself does not get redirected.

Why does the build version has this error, and how can I fix it?

The react project is using firebase if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure your **homepage** address is set to your website url, you can do that by going to package.json file in you project root and adding a homepage key with value of your website address.

If that did not solve your problem you can try to solve this problem by

1. **adding hash to your url before each route**: use HashRouter instead of browser route
2. **redirect every request to index.html**, so you should add the code below to .htaccess file in your Apache server:

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

Comment: where do I find my apache server though?

Comment: what do you mean, it's where you upload your build file.

Comment: I only use "npm run build", then "serve -s build".

Comment: ok, first of all make sure your home page address is correct, and you can add htaccess file  where you serve your build folder